# SCHTASKS Change Start Time of Task

Tags: shell, cmd, windows-task-scheduler

I checked this [link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc766442(v=ws.11).aspx) but got nowhere. When I try to change the start time of the Scheduled Task via `SCHTASKS /Change /TN /ST` I get an error "INVALID ARGUMENT /ST" How do i change Start Time of scheduled jobs on Windows w/o GUI?

EDIT: Running windows-XP /ST not supported.

Comment: You haven't told it a time. Type `schtasks /change /?`. From Help - */ST      starttime Specifies the start time to run the task. The time
format is HH:mm (24 hour time) for example, 14:30 for 2:30 PM.*

Comment: I already did that and still had error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
schtasks /TN myTaskName /CHANGE /ST 15:00
```

Comment: It doesn't work. The /ST is read as an invalid argument with /CHANGE. I only see this behavior with windows XP

Comment: And there's the critical bit of missing information ... Changing time isn't supported in XP. Delete and recreate the task instead. https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/schtasks.mspx?mfr=true